# How to find the specific files used in a Node.js app

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am starting my local project with an `npm start` command.

The project was built using the `npm install` and then `npm run build`.

I would like to edit one of the node_modules and change it's content, and then see that reflected in my running app. The problem is I do not know which file to edit - if I have this code

`import {x} from x`

And I have the directory x in my node_modules folder, is the process to find the running files

1. open the x directory, read the package.json file
2. go to the main entry there and go to the folder listed there
3. this file is the entry point and all the other files are loaded from here, as well as any dependencies listed in the package.json file

Is that it? Because I am editing the lib/index.js file but I do not see the changes reflected in my running codebase. the lib/index.js is the file referred to in the main entry of the package.json.

Is there perhaps some command I can run to show me which files I am using for a given node module?

Comment: You’d also want to check the `exports` field.

Comment: I often find it easiest to just set a breakpoint right before I call the function of interest in the module and then step into it.  That will show you exactly which file contains that function and where it is in your file system and you can then, once you know where it is, you can access it directly with your editor if that's what you're intending to do.

Comment: Also keep in mind that editing a JavaScript file that has already been loaded into a "running" process will not make any change in the running process.  You would have to restart the running process so it will then reload the modified Javascript file.